# How to perform commands after "setContentView" is being called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm using "include" on my main layout. Each one of them is a RelativeLayout which needs an OnClick listener to be attached, and update some information related.
So I've tried to do it simply by:

```
setContentView(R.layout.allobjects);
    ObjectListeners objectListeners = new ObjectListeners(objects);
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
    {           
        RelativeLayout objectBoxRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.object1 + i);            
        objectBoxRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(objectListeners.GetObjectListener(i));
        SomeObject currentObject = this.objects.get(i); 
        Object viewObject = findViewById(R.id.object1 + i);
        this.setObjectView(viewObject, currentObject);          
    }
```

The issue is that it takes too long after the "setContentView(R.layout.allobjects);" command, and the application shows black screen until it finish loading.
In addition, I use "setContentView(R.layout.allobjects);" after I perform the above commands. All of these commands have to be written after "setContentView(R.layout.allobjects);".

How can I handle that kind of situation ? Do I have to use onPreExecute and implement AsyncTask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AsyncTask is good solution to show loading dialog while these commands being executed.

**UPDATE:**

Add this class under your `onCreate()` function:

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            private ProgressDialog dialog;
            private Context context;

            public MyTask(Activity activity) {
                context = activity;
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            }

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
                dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                dialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //do your code here in background


             protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
                 dialog.dismiss();  

             }
}
```

then use the task inside `onCreate()` like this:

```
    MyTask mt = new MyTask(this);
    mt.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there other option then that ? Can you show me some code piece for doing that?

Comment: There is another way using thread, but asynctask is way better.. I will edit my answer to show you code

Comment: Now I'm getting an exception when trying to setContentView in the "doInBackground" method. android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: No, setcontentview has to be in your onCreate() other commands have to be in background only

Comment: Thanks. So in "doInBackground" I can't write commands that is related to the UI, correct ?

Comment: Am not sure but I think no, you have to deal with the UI in onPre and onPost only